# Cleaning data frames with rogue elements using split()

Tags: python, pandas, split, data-analysis, attributeerror

Given the following data in an excel sheet (taken in as a dataframe) :

```
    Name  Number       Date
    AA    '9988779911' '01-JAN-18'
    'BB'  '8779912044' '01-FEB-18'
```

I have used the following code to clean the dataframe and remove the unnecessary apostrophes;

```
for name in list(df):
    df[name] = df[name].str.split("'").str[1]
```

And I want the following output :

```
    Name  Number       Date
    AA    9988779911   01-JAN-18
    BB    8779912044   01-FEB-18
```

I am getting the following error :
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Thanks in advance for your help.:):)

Comment: Use `.str.strip("'")`

Comment: can you add the output of `df.info()` to your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip function is probably the shortest way here. The other answers are elegant too.

```
    str.strip("'")
```

Moshevi has said the same in one of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
for name in list(df):
    df[name] = df[name].str.replace("\'","")
```

Replace `'` with `empty` character.

Answer (score 0):

simpler approach

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace("'",""))
```